# Pinyin packages: accuracy and efficiency

Tags: python, nlp, cjk, pinyin

I am looking to get the pinyin of Simplified Mandarin characters, and have come across two packages:

- [pinyin 0.4.0](https://pypi.org/project/pinyin/) which is 6 years old ([GitHub repo here](https://github.com/lxyu/pinyin))
- [pinyin_jyutping_sentence](https://pypi.org/project/pinyin_jyutping_sentence/) which is 2> years old. ([GitHub repo here](https://github.com/Language-Tools/python-pinyin-jyutping-sentence))

Both offer similar features in terms of the ability to print character pinyin with and without the diacritics, but I am curious if one is more efficient than the other.

Right off the bat, I noticed that on the first `import pinyin_jyutping_sentence` that the package builds out a `Prefix dict`:

```
import pinyin_jyutping_sentence as pnyn
Building prefix dict from Path\to\python\lib\site-packages\pinyin_jyutping_sentence\dict.txt.big ...
Dumping model to file cache Path\to\AppData\Local\Temp\jieba.ue5a383df573783d4e379d21ab891d92a.cache
Loading model cost 0.793 seconds.
Prefix dict has been built successfully.
```

Whereas running `import pinyin` did *not* result in the creation of any kind of a dictionary.

Is there a difference between the two packages in speed and accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: Due to [StackOverflow's rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263724/unable-to-post-chinese-characters-due-to-validation-filter/263725#263725) about the inclusion of Mandarin characters, I was unable to include both the 294 character long mandarin string and 8-index long list of mandarin names I used to test this.**

---

Because this seems to be an obscure question for which there are no questions/answers here on StackOverflow, I did some quick efficiency/accuracy analysis for each package using `timeit` and `datetime`.

Here is the code:

```
'''
Test differences between pinyin packages
'''

import timeit
from datetime import datetime as dt
from tabulate import tabulate

# Timeit import statement for pinyin_jyutping_sentence
import_pinyin_jyutping_sentence = 'import pinyin_jyutping_sentence as pnyn1'

# Timeit import statement for pinyin
import_pinyin = 'import pinyin as pnyn2'

# Empty list to drop tabulate information into
table = []

# Test pinyin_jyutping_sentence package
pinyin_jyutping_sentence = '''
string1 = '[294 character string]'
list_of_names = [list, of, mandarin, names, len, is, 8, long]
pnyn1.pinyin(string1)
pinyin_list = [pnyn1.pinyin(e) for e in list_of_names]
'''
dt1_1 = dt.now()
pinyin_jyutping_sentence_timeit = timeit.timeit(setup=import_pinyin_jyutping_sentence, stmt=pinyin_jyutping_sentence, number=1000)
dt1_2 = dt.now()

# Calculate the pinyin_jyutping_sentence runtime with datetime
method1_time = dt1_2 - dt1_1

# Append runtime information to tabulate list
table.append(['pinyin_jyutping_sentence', pinyin_jyutping_sentence_timeit, method1_time])


## Test pinyin package
pinyin = '''
string1 = '[294 character string]'
list_of_names = [list, of, mandarin, names, len, is, 8, long]
pnyn2.get(string1)
pinyin_list = [pnyn2.get(e) for e in list_of_names]
'''

dt2_1 = dt.now()
pinyin_timeit = timeit.timeit(setup=import_pinyin, stmt=pinyin, number=1000)
dt2_2 = dt.now()
# Calculate the pinyin runtime with datetime
method2_time = dt2_2 - dt2_1

# Append runtime information to tabulate list
table.append(['pinyin', pinyin_timeit, method2_time])

print(tabulate(table, headers=['Package', 'Timeit', 'Datetime'], tablefmt='grid'))



import pinyin_jyutping_sentence as pyn1
import pinyin as pyn2

# String 1
print('String1')
string1 = '[294 character string]'
print(pyn1.pinyin(string1),'\n', pyn2.get(string1))
```

With the following output:

```
Building prefix dict from Path\to\python\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pinyin_jyutping_sentence\dict.txt.big ...
Loading model from cache Path\to\AppData\Local\Temp\jieba.ue5a383df573783d4e379d21ab891d92a.cache
Loading model cost 0.766 seconds.
Prefix dict has been built successfully.
+--------------------------+----------+----------------+
| Package                  |   Timeit | Datetime       |
+==========================+==========+================+
| pinyin_jyutping_sentence | 2.29024  | 0:00:15.148325 |
+--------------------------+----------+----------------+
| pinyin                   | 0.464655 | 0:00:00.588944 |
+--------------------------+----------+----------------+
String1
měiguó jīngjìxuéjiā màikè dùgéěr （ macdougail ） yú yījiǔliùlíng nián jiànlì le guójì zīběn yídòng de ⼀ bān móxíng ， yòu chēngwéi guójì tóuzī lìyì fēnpèi móxíng ， yòngyǐ fēnxī guójì zīběn yídòng kěnéng gěi dōngdàoguó dàilái de lìyì 。 qíhòu ， yòu yóu kěnpǔ děng rén jiàng gāi móxíng fāzhǎn chéng fēnxī jièdàizīběn guójì yùndòng zhōng shuāngfāng dāngshìguó lìyì fēnpèi de ⼀ bān gōngjù 。 zhèzhǒng yǐ guójiā wéi dānwèi de lìyì fēnpèi móxíng rútú yī  yī suǒshì 。 jiǎshè yǒujiǎ  yǐliǎngguó ， jiǎwéi zīběn chōngyù guó ， yǐwéi zīběn duǎnquē guó 。 jiǎguó yōngyǒu zīběn liàng ma ， yǐguó yōngyǒu zīběn liàng na 。 gēnjù biānjì chǎnchū dìjiǎn guīlǜ ， zài qítā yàosù tóurùliàng bùbiàn de qíngkuàng xià ， měi ⼀ zhuījiā zīběn de dānwèi chǎnchūlǜ dìjiǎn 。 jiǎdìng liǎng guónèi jūn cúnzài wánquán jìngzhēng ， zīběn de shōuyìlǜ děngyú zīběn de biānjì chǎnchūlǜ ， tú yī  yī zhōng eo biǎoshì jiǎguó de biānjì chǎnchū qūxiàn ， fo biǎoshì yǐguó de biānjì chǎnchū qūxiàn 。

 měiguójīngjìxuéjiāmàikèdùgéěr（Macdougail）yú1960niánjiànlìleguójìzīběnyídòngde⼀bānmóxíng，yòuchēngwèiguójìtóuzīlìyìfēnpèimóxíng，yòngyǐfēnxīguójìzīběnyídòngkěnénggěidōngdàoguódàiláidelìyì。qíhòu，yòuyóukěnpǔděngrénjiānggāimóxíngfāzhǎnchéngfēnxījièdàizīběnguójìyùndòngzhōngshuāngfāngdāngshìguólìyìfēnpèide⼀bāngōngjù。zhèzhǒngyǐguójiāwèidānwèidelìyìfēnpèimóxíngrútú1－1suǒshì。jiǎshèyǒujiǎ、yǐliǎngguó，jiǎwèizīběnchōngyùguó，yǐwèizīběnduǎnquēguó。jiǎguóyǒngyǒuzīběnliàngMA，yǐguóyǒngyǒuzīběnliàngNA。gēnjùbiānjìchǎnchūdìjiǎngūilv̀，zàiqítāyàosùtóurùliàngbùbiàndeqíngkuàngxià，měi⼀zhūijiāzīběndedānwèichǎnchūlv̀dìjiǎn。jiǎdìngliǎngguónèijūncúnzàiwánquánjìngzhēng，zīběndeshōuyìlv̀děngyúzīběndebiānjìchǎnchūlv̀，tú1－1zhōngEObiǎoshìjiǎguódebiānjìchǎnchūqūxiàn，FObiǎoshìyǐguódebiānjìchǎnchūqūxiàn。
```

Based on the output of the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) and [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) modules, [`pinyin_jyutping_sentence`](https://pypi.org/project/pinyin_jyutping_sentence/) is much slower than [`pinyin`](https://pypi.org/project/pinyin/). However, after examining the pinyin output of both `pinyin_jyutping_sentence` and `pinyin` in relation to one another and the original mandarin characters, `pinyin_jyutping_sentence` is far more accurate and readable.* `pinyin` contained several errors in it's output of the 294 character long string, and on closer examination of the pinyin output of the list of names, `pinyin` got the character tone wrong in several places, whereas `pinyin_jyutping_sentence` got it right in (as far as I was able to identify) every case. I will update this answer if I find/test other mandarin characters to pinyin packages in python.

*Interestingly, `pinyin_jyutping_sentence` converted numbers in the string into the number's corresponding pinyin.